# perl script for dinucleotide count of each sequence from a multi-sequence text file

Tags: regex, perl

I have a perl script which gives the sum result of all the sequences present in the multifasta (.txt format) input file. please help me in modifying the code in such a way that it gives result separately for each sequence .

input file seq:

```
>seq1  
GAA  
>seq2  
ALL
```

Expected output:

```
seq1
sum=1
abs=21
seq2
sum=1
abs=21
```

Actual script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print "Please type the filename of the DNA sequence MMta: ";
$str= <STDIN>;
chomp $str;
unless ( open(DNAFILE, $str) ) 
{
print "Cannot open file \"$str\"\n\n";
exit;
}
@str = <DNAFILE>;
$str=join('',@str);
print"\n DNA:\n
$str\n";

$GA = 0;
$AL = 0;
$MM = 0;
$DE = 0;
$DV = 0;
$VD = 0;
$DW = 0;
$QD = 0;
$SD = 0;
$DD = 0;
$ED = 0;
$DY = 0;
$VE = 0;
$EN = 0;
$II = 0;
$KE = 0;
$NV = 0;
$VP = 0;
$FV = 0;
$SS = 0;
$WK = 0;
$KK = 0;
$abs=0;

while ($str =~ /GA/ig)
{$GA++}
while ($str =~ /AL/ig)
{$AL++}
while ($str =~ /MM/ig)
{$MM++}
while ($str =~ /DE/ig)
{$DE++}
while ($str =~ /DV/ig)
{$DV++}
while ($str =~ /VD/ig)
{$VD++}
while ($str =~ /DW/ig)
{$DW++}
while ($str =~ /QD/ig)
{$QD++}
while ($str =~ /SD/ig)
{$SD++}
while ($str =~ /DD/ig)
{$DD++}
while ($str =~ /ED/ig)
{$ED++}
while ($str =~ /DY/ig)
{$DY++}
while ($str =~ /VE/ig)
{$VE++}
while ($str =~ /EN/ig)
{$EN++}
while ($str =~ /II/ig)
{$II++}
while ($str =~ /KE/ig)
{$KE++}
while ($str =~ /NV/ig)
{$NV++}
while ($str =~ /VP/ig)
{$VP++}
while ($str =~ /FV/ig)
{$FV++}
while ($str =~ /SS/ig)
{$SS++}
while ($str =~ /WK/ig)
{$WK++}
while ($str =~ /KK/ig)
{$KK++}
$total= "$GA+$AL+$MM+$DE+$DV+$VD+$DW+$QD+$SD+$DD+$ED+$DY+$VE+$EN+$II+$KE+$NV+$VP+$FV+$SS+$WK+$KK";
while ($total=~ /0/ig)
{$abs++}
$sum= $GA+$AL+$MM+$DE+$DV+$VD+$DW+$QD+$SD+$DD+$ED+$DY+$VE+$EN+$II+$KE+$NV+$VP+$FV+$SS+$WK+$KK;
print "GA = $GA\n";
print "AL = $AL\n";
print "WK = $MM\n";
print "DE = $DE\n";
print "VP = $DV\n";
print "VD = $VD\n";
print "DW = $DW\n";
print "QD = $QD\n";
print "SD = $SD\n";
print "DD = $DD\n";
print "ED = $ED\n";
print "DY = $DY\n";
print "VE = $VE\n";
print "EN = $EN\n";
print "II = $II\n";
print "KE = $KE\n";
print "NV = $NV\n";
print "VP = $VP\n";
print "FV = $FV\n";
print "SS = $SS\n";
print "WK = $WK\n";
print "KK = $KK\n";
print "sum=$sum\n";
print "abs=$abs";

$outputfile = "countbase.txt";
unless ( open(COUNTBASE, ">$outputfile") ) {
print "Cannot open file \"$outputfile\" to write
to!!\n\n";
exit;
}
print COUNTBASE "$sum
$abs";
close(COUNTBASE);


exit;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sir i know very little about the perl programming. I want a perl script which will give me the count of each dinucleotides i.e AT, AG, AC, AA, TA, TT, TC,TG, CC, CG, CA, CT, GG, GA, GC, GT present in each protein sequence from a multi-sequence file as a standard input.

Comment: @prosenjitpaul it might be not just perl programming you know little about. In your comment it sound like you want a count of nucleic acids pairs in amino acid sequence. The answer is 0 (you don't need a code for this).

Comment: You should post your input data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# ALLWAYS put these two lines at the beginig of each script
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(sum);

print "Please type the filename of the DNA sequence MMta: ";
my $file = <STDIN>;
chomp $file;
# Use three arg open and test for errors
open my $fh_in, '<', $file or die "Unable to open '$file': $!";

my %count;
my $seq;
# loop on every lines of input file
while(my $line = <$fh_in>) {
    chomp $line;
    # Find the sequence name
    $seq = $1 if $line =~ />(\w+)/;
    # Count
    while($line =~ /(GA|AL|MM|DE|DV|VD|DW|QD|SD|DD|ED|DY|VE|EN|II|KE|NV|VP|FV|SS|WK|KK)/ig) {
        $count{$seq}{$1}++;
    }
}

open my $fh_out, '>', 'countbase.txt' or die "Unable to open 'countbase.txt': $!";
# Display the result separately for each sequence
foreach(keys %count) {
    my $sum = sum(values %{$count{$_}});
    my $abs = 22 - scalar keys %{$count{$_}};
    print $fh_out $_,"\nsum = ",$sum,"\nabs = ", $abs,"\n";
}
```

Comment: Sir this code also gives the result taking the sum of all the dipeptides from all the sequences...... Sir i want the result separately for each sequence. One more thing is that the count should be from the sequences only excluding the header line.

Comment: @prosenjitpaul: Sorry, I don't get you. I've tried with you sample file and it is working fine. May be the sequence's name is not `>seq1`. Please edit your question and add a significant extract of input file.

Comment: thanks sir.you are right ....now i changed the sequence header name and it worked.......thanks a lot sir

Comment: The while function does not counts the overlapping di-peptides present in the sequence. Is there any alternative way to do so...

Comment: @prosenjitpaul: It's too vague. Please edit your question and add a significant extract of input file and expected result.